# I Want to Write this Trigger as Bulkify How Should do that?

Tags: trigger

```
trigger ChildtoParentUpdate_Conidtions on Opportunity (before update) {
    for(opportunity opp:trigger.new)
    {
       if(opp.stagename=='Closed won')
       {
         opp.Description='Congratulations'+'  '+opp.name+'   '+'Your Stage isin::'+opp.stagename;
       }
       if(opp.stagename=='Qualification')
       {
         opp.Description='Congratulations'+'   '+opp.name+'   '+'Your Stage isin::'+opp.stagename;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to bulkify here? What is wrong with the existing trigger?

Comment: The real question is why is this a trigger... you can accomplish this with a simple workflow rule... dont overcomplicate it when you dont need to.

Comment: Take a look at David Liu's tutorial's for new developers, including the section on [bulkifying code](http://www.sfdc99.com/2014/01/18/bulkifying-code/) They're far easier to understand and adopt than the Salesforce guides, although the new [Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/force_com_dev_beginner/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk) resources are pretty good.

Answer (score 7):

Your trigger is already bulk safe:

1. Before update
2. no SOQL Queries
3. Simple in that it only updates fields based on another field value

Bulkification is only required if you are performing Queries, cross object DML, etc where the logic is not straight forward or working on records other than what is in the trigger context.

Answer (score 1):

In your case since there is no DML statement or SOQL queries are not involved, there is nothing much to bulkify. But some minor updates can be useful, second if condition will be better if you are putting it in else condition.

```
trigger ChildtoParentUpdate_Conidtions on Opportunity (before update) {
for(opportunity opp:trigger.new){
    if(opp.stagename=='Closed won'){
        opp.Description='Congratulations'+'  '+opp.name+'   '+'Your Stage isin::'+opp.stagename;
    }else if(opp.stagename=='Qualification'){
        opp.Description='Congratulations'+'   '+opp.name+'   '+'Your Stage isin::'+opp.stagename;
    }
}
```

}

Another common coding standard is, externalizing the code to another one handler/helper class

Answer (score 0):

As far as the existing trigger is concerned it it alrady bulkified and if any change is required then it max be to else apart from that i don't think any changes are required.

```
trigger ChildtoParentUpdate_Conidtions on Opportunity (before update) {
for(opportunity opp:trigger.new)
{
 if(opp.stagename=='Closed won'){
 opp.Description='Congratulations'+'      '+opp.name+'   '+'Your Stage is     in::'+opp.stagename;
 }
 else(opp.stagename=='Qualification'){
opp.Description='Congratulations'+'     '+opp.name+'    '+'Your Stage is   in::'+opp.stagename;
 }
}
 update opp;    
}
```